# Change type of a column with numbers from varchar to int

Tags: sql-server, types

We have two columns in a database which is currently of type varchar(16). Thing is, it contains numbers and always will contain numbers. We therefore want to change its type to integer. But the problem is that it of course already contains data.

Is there any way we can change the type of that column from varchar to int, and not lose all those numbers that are already in there? Hopefully some sort of sql we can just run, without having to create temporary columns and create a C# program or something to do the conversion and so forth... I imagine it could be pretty easy if SQL Server have some function for converting strings to numbers, but I am **very** unstable on SQL. Pretty much only work with C# and access the database through LINQ to SQL.

**Note:** Yes, making the column a varchar in the first place was not a very good idea, but that is unfortunately the way they did it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The only reliable way to do this will be using a temporary table, but it will not be much SQL:

```
select * into #tmp from bad_table
truncate table bad_table
alter bad_table alter column silly_column int
insert bad_table
select cast(silly_column as int), other_columns
from #tmp
drop table #tmp
```

Comment: #tmp is a random name of a tmp table?

Comment: Good answer - I would run this first - select cast(silly_column as int), other_columns
from bad_table
To make sure you don't have any conversion issues and they are all in fact ints.

Comment: haha, no no, I was wondering if the # character was what made it a temp table. or if it is just any name that doesn't already exist, or how it works...

Comment: A single # denotes a connection specific temp table (only available in that ocnnection) whereas a double hash ## denotes a global temp table (accessible by all connections)

Comment: ah, nice, ok. then I think I got it *opening management studio to try it out*

Comment: *sigh* truncate doesn't work because of a foreign key constraint. can I somehow disable that while I mess with it and then turn it back on afterwards?

Comment: you can indeed, although it might be better if you do it in management studio than rely on my code from memory

Comment: i was doing it in management studio. but by trying to write the query... is there another way of doing it? (also, is there any way to.. dry run a query? to see what it _would_ do, if you actually ran it?)

Comment: @Svish . I have fall in a same problem. In my case I am using mysql. In my database a column `year` will be always numeric value. But in my database this column is `varchar`. I want to change that existing database column to `int` without losing any value. Can you help me to solve that problem ?

Comment: I was not able to perform, because I'd a UNIQUE KEY constraint on the column which needs to get altered ( from varchar to int ). I dropped the constraint, and added it back at later on and worked!

Answer (score 33):

The easiest way to do this is:

```
alter table myTable alter column vColumn int;
```

This will work as long as

1. all of the data will fit inside an int
2. all of the data can be converted to int (i.e. a value of "car" will fail)
3. there are no indexes that include vColumn.  If there are indexes, you will need to include a drop and create for them to get back to where you were.

Comment: @svish: I really did want it to be "car" not 'char'.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. Understand what you meant by it now, hehe :)

Comment: this worked a treat. It was failing when attempting through management studio

Comment: @jmoreno is there any way i can Alter or Update table with `order by LENGTH(col)`???

Comment: @AshishKamble: that would have to be a separate questions, with more details explaining just what you want.

Answer (score 8):

Just change the datatype in SQL Server Management Studio.

(You may need to go to menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Designers*, and disable the option that prevents saving changes that re-create the table.)

Comment: wont I lose all the values then??

Comment: No. Try it on a test table if you want?

Comment: I've just done this and it worked perfectly. First I've checked if all existing values were numbers stored in string type and if I could successfully convert all varchars to numeric type. After I disabled all references to the column (Indexes, Keys, Triggers, ...) and went on and aplied the change in MSSMS.
Great!

Comment: this failed for me, but the above alter table statement worked

Comment: Doing in SSMS  in Design menu **for a large table** may pre-warn you: `Saving Definition Changes to tables with large amounts of data could take a considerable amount of time. While changes are being saved, table data will not be accessible.`, or may fail:  `- Unable to modify table. Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`, unless you change the `Tools → Options → Designers` option "Override connection string time-out for table designer updates". I also think the `ALTER TABLE` statement may be better for me.

Answer (score 2):

I totally appreciate the previous answers, but also thought a more complete answer would be helpful to other searchers...

There are a couple caveats that would be helpful if you making the changes on a production type table.

1. If you have an **identity** column defined on the table you will have to set `IDENTITY_INSERT` on and off around the re-insert of data.  You will also have to use an explicit column list.
2. If you want to be sure of not killing data in the database, use `TRANSACTIONS` around the truncate/alter/reinsert process
3. If you have a lot of data, then trying to just make the change in SQ Server Management Studio could fail with a timeout and you could lose data.

To expand the answer that @cjk gave, look at the following:

Note: 'tuc' is just a placeholder in this script for the real tablename

```
begin try 
  begin transaction

  print 'Selecting Data...'
  select * into #tmp_tuc from tuc

  print 'Truncating Table...'
  truncate table tuc

  alter table tuc alter column {someColumnName} {someDataType} [not null]
  ... Repeat above until done

  print 'Reinserting data...'
  set identity_insert tuc on
  insert tuc (
    <Explicit column list (all columns in table)>
  )
  select  
    <Explicit column list (all columns in table - same order as above)>
  from #tmp_tuc
  set identity_insert tuc off

  drop table #tmp_tuc
  commit
  print 'Successful!'
end try
begin catch
  print 'Error - Rollback'
  if @@trancount > 0
    rollback

  declare @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int
  select @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()

  set identity_insert tuc off

  RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)
end catch
```