# Change a database column type while ignoring conversion errors using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, types

This is similar to a previous question [MSSQL: Change type of a column with numbers from varchar to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577712/mssql-change-type-of-a-column-with-numbers-from-varchar-to-int), except in this case not all of the original data can be successfully converted from varchar to int.  In these cases, I want the output to just be `NULL`.

For example, the incoming set of values in a varchar column will look like: `{'123', '234', '345', 'A', '456'}`.  After conversion from varchar to int, I want the column to contain the values `{123, 234, 345, NULL, 456}`.  In practice, I'll have about 99% success rate.

While a general solution would be ideal, I am using SQL Server 2005 and need to perform the change in Transact SQL.

EDIT: The `IsNumeric` suggestions do bridge a portion of the gap, but are not complete.  For example, if the data set includes numeric but not integer data, the `IsNumeric` fix doesn't work (and there doesn't appear to be a `IsInteger`).  In particular, the following set will not convert {'123.456', '$12'} where they are both numeric according to SQL Server `IsNumeric` but will not convert to `Int`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Run an update thus:

   ..
   SET
       OldValue = CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Oldvalue) = 1 THEN Oldvalue ELSE NULL END
   ...
2. Run

   ALTER TABLE dbo.Mytable ALTER COLUMN OldValue int --Add NULL or NOT NULL as needed

Answer (score 2):

1. Execute this first:

   update table set field = null where ISNUMERIC(field) = 0
2. Then change the type

Answer (score 2):

After an hour of hacking around and with guidance from other answers, here's what I've come up with:

1. Clean up the data to ensure that information will convert.  Since there is no IsInteger function, use IsNumeric to set to `NULL` anything that can't convert at all.
2. Convert all remaining data to type `MONEY` which will effectively get rid of the currency symbols that were previously accepted by `IsNumeric`.
3. Convert the money type to an integer to get rid of the fraction.
4. Finally, change the data type.

The following test demonstrates using SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ( 
    id INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    col VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO tbl (col) VALUES ('123')
INSERT INTO tbl (col) VALUES ('ABC')
INSERT INTO tbl (col) VALUES ('123.456')
INSERT INTO tbl (col) VALUES ('$12')

UPDATE tbl SET col = CASE WHEN IsNumeric(col) = 1 THEN Convert(INTEGER, (Convert(MONEY, col))) ELSE NULL END
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER COLUMN col INTEGER

SELECT * FROM tbl
```