# SQL Converting real to INT, is it possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got a table that has a column with **real** as its datatype, I am trying to update it and edit the **real values to int values**. Is it possible? If yes, then please give me a query because I tried a lot and the result was just an epic fail.
What I tried (Didn't work at all)

```
UPDATE _Table set column = REPLACE(column,'.%','')
```

That query didn't work, Is there any possible solution for my problem?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try the answers of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577712/change-type-of-a-column-with-numbers-from-varchar-to-int ?

Comment: Yep, and non of them has worked since it is not related to my question.

Comment: Ok. Your question was not very clear (imho) and I thought you wanted to change the type of the column.

Answer (score 0):

You could just truncate the values. Surprisingly enough, this is done with the [`round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003(SQL.90).aspx) function, by having the third parameter a non-zero value. Here I used `1`, for no particular reason:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    mycolumn = ROUND(mycolumn, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you =) It's fine now.