# Change foreign key type without losing data.(asp.net)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have created one to many relationship between student and department tables using entity framework.But unfortunately in the student table the foreign key (DepartmentId) type I gave string but it should be int.How can i resolve this issue without losing data????????

N.B: I am using entity framework code first approach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577712/change-type-of-a-column-with-numbers-from-varchar-to-int

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do that, considering that your DepartamentID is the PK of the table Departament, so you have to drop the old field and create a new one, something like this

```
AddColumn("dbo.Departament", "DepartamentID2", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
Sql(@"
    UPDATE dbp.Departament
    SET DepartamentID2 = DepartamentID
    ");

Sql(@"
        ALTER TABLE dbo.Departament drop CONSTRAINT <The FK Constraint>
        ");
DropColumn("dbo.Departament", "DepartamentID");
RenameColumn("dbo.Departament", "DepartamentID2", "DepartamentID");

Sql(@"
        ALTER TABLE dbo.Departament add PRIMARY KEY (DepartamentID)
        ");

Sql(@"
            ALTER TABLE dbo.Departament add CONSTRAINT <The FK 
  constraint>
            ");
```